SwapRouter02 not working with custom ERC20 token
I am trying to programmatically swap ETH for a custom ERC 20 token (let me take a meme token as an example)
Here is my code that I swapped ETH for USDC:
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { fs } = require("fs");
require("dotenv").config();
const SWAP_ROUTER02_ABI = require("./ABIs/SwapRouter02.json");

const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.BASE_RPC);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

const SWAP_ROUTER02_ADDRESS = "0x2626664c2603336E57B271c5C0b26F421741e481";
const WETH_ADDRESS = "0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006";
const USDC_ADDRESS = "0x833589fcd6edb6e08f4c7c32d4f71b54bda02913";

const router = new ethers.Contract(
  SWAP_ROUTER02_ADDRESS,
  SWAP_ROUTER02_ABI,
  signer
);

async function main() {
  const inputAmount = ethers.parseEther("0.0001");

  const params = {
    tokenIn: WETH_ADDRESS,
    tokenOut: USDC_ADDRESS,
    fee: 3000,
    recipient: signer.address,
    amountIn: inputAmount,
    amountOutMinimum: 0,
    sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0,
  };

  const data = router.interface.encodeFunctionData("exactInputSingle", [
    params,
  ]);

  const txArgs = {
    to: SWAP_ROUTER02_ADDRESS,
    value: inputAmount,
    data: data,
    gasLimit: "300000",
  };

  const tx = await signer.sendTransaction(txArgs);
  const reciept = await tx.wait();
  console.log(reciept.hash);
}

main();

When I executed the code above, it went well: Base Scan
However, when I change USDC_ADDRESS to some other meme coins, i.e 0x8D70e2C2cB0dD6a5F6670FCA157754e922B1E245, I got the error transaction execution reverted
So my questions are:

What is the problem here?
Do I have to specify any pool with its fees or anything to swap?


Needs more information. Usually is some tax mechanic in the s- coin. Sometimes a badly written one that is hard to get around, other times it's just a case of needing to account for the tax on transfer in the minimum amount out or max amount in. Show a transaction hash from a fail and can troubleshoot the specific case.

In your case the pool doesn't exist. Token addresses plus fee compute the address and there isn't one with those tokens and that fee.

Usually is some tax mechanic in the s- coin. Sometimes a badly written one that is hard to get around, other times it's just a case of needing to account for the tax on transfer in the minimum amount out or max amount in
Judging from this transaction at the same address:

https://basescan.org/tx/0x5bc2be81f0e11fa9e10e379458a02860c1fa7e2696b0867a5af1ad5cd4576a9b

It seems it is just a case of not passing a path that exists.

The pool being computed is: 0x1d1a15d767dd76521f9476b0395a03924a2b6407

https://basescan.org/address/0x1d1a15d767dd76521f9476b0395a03924a2b6407

Which has no liquidity and has never been seeded.
Tiers are 0.01%, 0.05%, 0.3%, and 1%
100 | 500 |3000 | 10000
Check a pool exists by calling the factory contract getPool and passing both token addresses and fee tier, call reserves or get a quote through the quoter to check it is seeded with enough liquidity, before trying to swap on it.

So I have to get the pool with each corresponding fee tiers, and find ones that have enough liquidity to swap, right?

Exactly that. Else you might use other methods such as a subgraph query for the pair with those tokens ordered by tvl for example. | https://cryptomarketpool.com/use-the-graph-to-query-ethereum-data-in-python/
